# RVM install issues on a local user account

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu server

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:            11.10
Codename:       oneiric
```

When I try to install RVM for a local user I get the following:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm': Permission denied
```

What is the issues here?

Ho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the '-k' switch to the curl command:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Answer (score -1):

As documented on [official help](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/#explained), RVM should try to install to `/usr/local/rvm` if you are running installation prefixed with `sudo`.

If running as normal user, RVM should install to ~/.rvm